# Phone Number Validation Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, input

I am having a issue validating phone number. The phone number is a 10 digit string that should be populated in a three input field 
1st input field - have only 3 digits only ( requires, can accept only numbers and max length 3)
2nd input field - have only 3 digits only ( requires, can accept only numbers and max length 3)
3rd input field - have only 4 digits only ( requires, can accept only numbers and max length 4)

and tab should be moved to next input field, when maximum number of characters have been implemented in the first one
the fields should be red, when none of the above conditions are not meeting

```
<label for="phoneone" aria-label="Enter First 3 digits of your phone no."><input id="phoneone" type="number" required name="phoneone" class="phone-text-box" ng-model="user.phoneNumbercodeone"  ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="3" maxlength="3" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"></input></label>
                        <label for="phonetwo" aria-label="Enter second 3 digits of your phone no."><input id="phonetwo" type="number" required  name="phonetwo" class="phone-text-box" ng-model="user.phoneNumbercodetwo" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="3" maxlength="3" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"></input></label>
                        <label for="phonethree" aria-label="Enter last 4 digits of your phone no."><input id="phonethree" type="number" required  name="phonethree" class="phone-text-box" ng-model="user.phoneNumbercodethree" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="4" maxlength="4" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"></input></label>
                        <div class="clearfix" ></div>
```

how would i achieve the above validation conditions using input html tag

Comment: if you only want to validate by html tag should look something like this `<input type="number" name="phone[]" min="3" max="3" tabindex="1" required >`

Comment: i tried couple of conditions, but it isn't working for me. The pattern should be matching to only numbers as well

Comment: Share what you have tried so far

Comment: please find the attached code snippet. The above code is not working for me. what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You should use input pattern validation. This can be done using the ng-pattern directive:

NgPattern sets pattern validation error key if the ngModel value does not match a RegExp found by evaluating the Angular expression given in the attribute value. If the expression evaluates to a RegExp object, then this is used directly. If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in ^ and $ characters. For instance, "abc" will be converted to new RegExp('^abc$').

Note: Avoid using the g flag on the RegExp, as it will cause each successive search to start at the index of the last search's match, thus not taking the whole input value into account.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of small issues with your code. Specifically I am looking at `ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="3" maxlength="3" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"`. You can achieve your number validation using the html5 properties of `min` and `max` on your input. So your input would look something like this:

```
<input id="phoneone" type="number" name="phoneone" class="phone-text-box" ng-model="user.phoneNumbercodeone" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="3" min="100" max="999" />
```

And then you can run validations against that using something like this:

```
<div ng-show="phoneForm.phoneone.$invalid && phoneForm.phoneone.$dirty">
    <div ng-show="phoneForm.phoneone.$error.minlength || phoneForm.phoneone.$error.maxlength">This must be a 3 digit number</div>
</div>
```

Of course exchanging out phoneForm for the name of your form.

Comment: The `ng-minlength` and `ng-maxlength` determines how long the input field should be in characters. `min` and `max` determine the numeric values allowed in the field.

Comment: can you explain me why we are using ng-show div here ? is it necessary for the conditions i am checking for getting proper phone format

Comment: iam very confused. can someone post the working code snippet for the one i have posted

Comment: The div is just to show the validation. So when the input value is $invalid and $dirty, that div will show an error message. Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/liwamupiri/edit?html,js,output) example to help you get started with the validation.

Comment: Did this help you resolve the validation problem on your application? If it has and you accept my answer, I'll up vote your question.